# Copy data from container to another one with Jenkins running in one of these container

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use two Docker containers. One contains the Jenkins application and the other is a Nginx server. I am building a React application with Jenkins and I would like to copy my Dist file into the Nginx container. How can I do it?

I try to do something like that:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPA7s.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to achieve this is using a volume. Use a "nginx_data" volume which will be mounted inside the Nginx containers www folder and at the same time mount the volume inside the Jenkins container. Then you can simply copy files to that volume location inside the Jenkins container and it will automatically be visible inside Nginx's container. More on volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).